# Storing CLLocation (latitude, longtitude data) in to Core Data

Tags: core-data, core-location, locationmanager, cllocation

i want to ask a question about core location and core data. i looked some questions but couldnt do that..
i have a application which stores some textfields, photos, date and time datas in UITableView With core data, i stored everything (photos, texts, date etc.) Now trying to store Location data i couldnt do.

this is some of my code here.

```
    #pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    NSDateFormatter *myFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [myFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"];
    [myFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    todaysDate = [myFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    myDateLabel.text = todaysDate;

    UIView *patternBg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
    patternBg.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background01.png"]];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = patternBg;

    // If we are editing an existing picture, then put the details from Core Data into the text fields for displaying

    if (currentPicture)
    {
        [companyNameField setText:[currentPicture companyName]];
        [myDateLabel setText:[currentPicture currentDate]];

        if ([currentPicture photo])
            [imageField setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[currentPicture photo]]];
    }
}
```

in the saveButton

```
    - (IBAction)editSaveButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // For both new and existing pictures, fill in the details from the form
    [self.currentPicture setCompanyName:[companyNameField text]];
    [self.currentPicture setCurrentDate:[myDateLabel text]];
    [self.currentPicture setCurrentTime:[myTimeLabel text]];
    [self.currentPicture setLatitudeData:[_latitudeLabel text]];
    [self.currentPicture setLongtidueData:[_longtitudeLabel text]];

}
```

and last one, my locationManager's method..

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        _longtitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
         [self->locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }


}
```

i tried "[locationmanager stopUpdatingLocation];" many times, but when i entered the app, code starts to calculating latitude and longtitude data, i just want to take that data 1 time, and store..

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain: 'code starts to calculating latitude and longtitude data' and how this relates to the callback 'locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:'.

Comment: i just need, do-while i guess.. when the user open this app, this code is working.. 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
        
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

i need to call this one time.. then i can store it

Answer (score 0):

If calling `stopUpdatingLocation` doesn't stop location updates, then most likely `self->locationManager` is nil. That would mean you're not really making the call.

It's hard to be sure exactly why this would happen, except that your code seem to make a point of **not** using any semantics implied by a `@property` declaration. Just assigning to `location` in `viewDidLoad` avoids any declaration, and looking up the manager using `self->locationManager` does as well. Assuming that `location` is a property, you should assign it to `self.locationManager`, and use that when looking it up as well.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (locationAge > 5) return;  // ignore cached location, we want current loc

    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 0) return;  // ignore invalid

    // wait for GPS accuracy (will be < 400)
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 400) {
        _longtitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
         [manager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your didUpdateToLocation do this code

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

  NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
  if (locationAge > 5) return;

  // ignore cached location, we want current loc
  if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= 0) return;  // ignore invalid

  // wait for GPS accuracy (will be < 400)
  if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 400) {
      _longtitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.longitude];
      _latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", newLocation.coordinate.latitude];
       [manager stopUpdatingLocation];

  //assign nil to locationManager object and delegate
       locationManager.delegate = nil;
       locationManager = nil;

  }

}

Thanks.